# SearchRequestBuilder: is there a way to ask to return all fields?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the Java API to query elasticsearch. I am building the query this way:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch(index)
            .setQuery(query)
            .addFieldDataField("location")
            .addField("time")
            .addField("name");
SearchResponse resp = searchRequestBuilder.get();
for (SearchHit hit : resp.getHits().getHits()) {
   GeoPoint point = hit.field("location").getValue();
   // ... etc 
}
```

Is there a way to build the request and just get all the fields without specifying them explicitly? Seeing as the HTTP interface doesn't require you to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of ES and java client you're on, but according to this javadoc: http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/HEAD/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder.html#addFields(java.lang.String...), If you don't specify any fields, the full _source of the document will be returned.

Another thing I'll note is that the javadoc specifies the fields must be stored (unless you use addFieldDataField). Make sure they're not marked as ignored in your mapping.

Comment: Thanks @hansod1, I simply missed that.